# Problem with Arduino using arrays in Structure

Tags: arrays, struct, arduino

With an Arduino Uno I'm having a problem that is probably simple to solve for somebody who knows what they're doing. I'm trying to get this code to print out "-30" but all I get is "0" no matter what value I put in "setpt[x]" in the serial.print line in loop().

Thanks in advance, Don

```
typedef struct
{
  byte seg_num[12];
  byte ramp_hrs[12];
  int  setpt[12];
  byte ramp_mins[12];
}record_type;

record_type profile[8];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("*** START ***");
}

void loop()
{
  profile[0] = (record_type) {(1,2,3),(5,7,9),(-40,-30,-25),(2,4,6)};
  
  Serial.println(profile[0].setpt[2]); // fails with setpt[from 0 to 3]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Comma operators* are used in your expressions like `(1,2,3)`.

`(1,2,3)` is equivalent to `3` here.

You should use `{}` instead of `()` to initialize each arrays.

```cpp
profile[0] = (record_type) {{1,2,3},{5,7,9},{-40,-30,-25},{2,4,6}};
```

Then, correct the index to get `-30` instead of `-25`.

```cpp
Serial.println(profile[0].setpt[1]);
```